# Python BeautifulSoup Returning Top Row Only

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been learning to scrape websites with BeautifulSoup, and it has been going well. Borrowing code, I have managed to scrape certain websites.  When I reached the website below, however, I am only returning the top row of the table.  I noticed in the html that the website coder has made the header row a td tag instead of th tag, and I was wondering if that could be causing my problem.  If so, is there a work around? Am I missing something obvious?  I have tried using the different parsers.

```
    url = 'https://www.twinspires.com/php/brisstats/report.php?bris_id=4061015&report=activity'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'html5lib')

    data = []
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'reporttable'})
    rows = table.findAll('tr')

    for row in rows:
        print row
        cols = table.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
     print data
```

idle output for the print row and data statements

```html
<tr>
<td class="field-title" width="15%">Activity</td>
<td class="field-title" width="10%">Date</td>
<td class="field-title" width="10%">Track</td>
<td class="field-title" width="9%">Distance</td>
<td class="field-title" width="5%">Surf</td>
<td class="field-title" width="5%">Cond</td>
<td class="field-title" width="9%">Time</td>
<td class="field-title" width="10%">Class</td>
<td class="field-title" width="5%">Fin</td>
<td class="field-title">Comment</td>
</tr>
```

```
[[u'Activity', u'Date', u'Track', u'Distance', u'Surf', u'Cond', u'Time', u'Class', u'Fin', u'Comment']]
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to scrape the *contents* of the table? Unfortunately, the table itself, aside from the (mis-tagged) header row, is generated by JavaScript, so you'll need to use something like `selenium` or `phantomjs` to render the *final* HTML before you can scrape it. You can view the rendered HTML using your browser's Developer Tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual data in the table is being populated using javascript, which is why it is not visible to BeautifulSoup.

Luckily for you, this coder has hard-coded the username and password for the remote service that is returning the data being used to populate the table:

```
<script>
    var brisid ='4061015';
    $(document).ready(function (){
      var crossDomainUrl = 'https://www.twinspires.com/php/fw/php_BRIS_BatchAPI/2.3/Brisstats/activity?bris_id=4061015&username=username&password=password&output=json';
      $.ajax({ url: crossDomainUrl,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: 'jsonpcallback',
          jsonpCallback: 'dispdata'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using the excellent `requests` library, this is as simple as:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = `https://www.twinspires.com/php/fw/php_BRIS_BatchAPI/2.3/Brisstats/activity?bris_id=4061015&username=username&password=password&output=json`
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> data = r.json()
>>> data['activity']['activity-log-proc']['activity-logs']['activity-log'][0]
{u'comment': u'bmp brk,ins to 5/16pl', u'Distance': u'1m', u'Finish': u'4', u'laid_off': [], u'country': u'USA', u'time': [], u'surface': u'T', u'track_id': u'BEL - 09', u'track_condition': u'FM', u'race_number': u'9', u'race_type': u'Race-green', u'day_evening': u'D', u'horse_name': u'Antebellum', u'race_date': u'15Jun16', u'date': u'2016-06-15 00:00:00.0', u'class': u'MCL40000'}
```

You can then loop through `data['activity']['activity-log-proc']['activity-logs']['activity-log']` to get all the results:

```
for i in data['activity']['activity-log-proc']['activity-logs']['activity-log']:
  print(i['track_condition'])  # etc.
```